Headless Chrome not invoking in Behat
Here is my behat.yaml file
default:
  autoload:
    '': '%paths.base%/context'
  extensions:
    DMore\ChromeExtension\Behat\ServiceContainer\ChromeExtension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      browser_name: chrome
      sessions:
        default:
          chrome:
            socket_timeout : 60
            api_url: "http://localhost:9222"

And the command which I used to invoke headless chrome is
chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222

I want to invoke headless chrome to run behat tests using Selenium and mink.
However I am getting the error
Could not fetch version information from http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version. Check if Chrome is running. See docs/troubleshooting.md if Chrome crashed unexpectedly.
Json Error: Syntax error.

